# Media queries not working when changing screen resolution but working when changing width and height google responsive developer tools checking

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Hi am trying to apply the css when screen resolution is 1280*720 its not applied but when I manually enter width and height in google responsive check its working . Here is code of css

```
 @media (min-height:720px) and (min-width: 1280px) {
     .space
       {
            margin-top:24.5%;
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want it from `720px to 1280px` then you have to use `media query` `min-width:720px` (i.e. from 720px) to `max-width:1280px` (i.e. less then 1280px) as below,

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #111;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 720px) and (max-width: 1280px) {
  div {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Scale your browser and see div background change.

Comment: I want it for min-height is 720px and min-width is 1280px

Comment: @IvoryFabian In that way your styling keeps on going from 720px to till the user screen resolution instead you could style from min to max. Or define to different media media screen and(min-width:720px) then another as same media screen and(min-width:1280px)

Comment: I want difference when changing height is screen resolution not width you are saying samething only width

Comment: @IvoryFabian Check this jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/juoqoy07/ if both conditions are met then only div background color changes, scale that and try.

Answer (score 0):

On desktop systems, the size considered by media queries like `min-height` is the size of the *content area* of the browser, not the resolution of the screen. A system with a 1280x720 screen will not use rules in this media query unless the browser is in in full-screen mode, since some of the screen is being used for the browser toolbar and scrollbar, window decorations, a taskbar (on Windows) or menubar (on macOS), *etc*.

Comment: then how can i give margin based on height

Comment: You can. It's just based on the height of the browser content, not the height of the screen.